# OpenSSL API's to pass EC named curve list while generating SSL CTX?

Tags: tls, cryptography, openssl, ecc

I need to pass the selected EC named curve list to server. Could someone please let me know the OpenSSL API to achieve the same while generating the SSL_CTX?

Comment: Programming questions are better asked at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes , i will make note of it and I did post  it there too but no luck so far :(